# Where is the path to put drivers for WSO2 ENTREPRISE INTEGRATOR 6.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Quick+Start+Guide

I am trying the example with WSO2 EI, and specifically for data services.
Mysql Driver should be copied into ./wso2/repository/components/lib directory that doesn't exist anymore then I try to put it into ./wso2/repository/components/plugins, with no more chance.
Is there any other repository where it should be or a parameter to change ?
Many thanks in advance
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it to EI_HOME/lib directory.